# Getting data from streamlit instance

Tags: python, streamlit

I made a streamlit app that locally writes to a CSV on the instance, and just realized now i have no way to get that data. I am pretty sure if I push up a change via github it'll overwrite the DB (can I use a gitignore maybe?)

Pretty dumb problem, open to any suggestions how to recover the data :)

Answer (score 0):

To recover the data, you need to access the CSV file directly on the instance where the Streamlit app is running. You can try using a file transfer protocol (FTP) client to connect to the instance and download the CSV file. If you're on windows you'd use WinSCP for linux and Mac there is Filezilla.

For future purposes, it's better to use a database for storage and retrieval like MySQL or PostgresDB. You could also store the CSV in storage facility like S3 as a last resort. But Databases are the way to go.

Also yes you could add the CSV to your .gitignore file.